# Styling the text on each side of a <input type="range"> tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to add some CSS styling to the words that are on either side of the  tags.

[image: screenshot of the finished effect]

Here is my code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend><br>
        <label for="height" class="margin">Height:</label>
        Short<input type="range" id="height" name="height" min="0" max="100">Tall<br>
        <label for="salary" class="margin">Salary:</label>
        Poor<input type="range" id="salary" name="salary" min="0" max="100">Rich
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @DannyBarber Not really. I'm new to coding so I take classes to improve. I have everything done except this. I've tried using <span> <div> <p> adding classes and id but nothing I do gives me the affect I need.

Comment: @DannyBarber, Unfortunately this is a homework question. It's the very first assignment for a Coursera course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript

Comment: @Kim, is the coursera course forum not able to provide help and advice regarding your problem? If you've made an attempt, that at least shows you have made the effort and you can show what you have done and get feedback. If you rely on SO to do your homework, your really just cheating yourself through the course. Also, if they get wind of this, you could be removed from the course as the work is not your own. Please keep this in mind when working through these assignments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the text on either side in spans with classes, then style them by class via CSS as follows.

**Live Demo:**

```css
fieldset > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.leftlabel, .rightlabel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftlabel {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.rightlabel {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend><br>
      <label for="height" class="margin">Height:</label>
      <span class="leftlabel">Short</span>
      <input type="range" id="height" name="height" min="0" max="200" style="width: 200px">
      <span class="rightlabel">Tall</span>
      <br>
      <label for="salary" class="margin">Salary:</label>
      <span class="leftlabel">Poor</span>
      <input type="range" id="salary" name="salary" min="0" max="200" style="width: 200px">
      <span class="rightlabel">Rich</span>
  </fieldset>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/sf2cz8yL/3/

Comment: @maximillian...I've tried this exact code but I still can't get the background to style evenly. I've played with the box model all the ways I can think of.

Comment: @Kim What do you mean by get the background to style evenly? Are you trying to change the background of the fieldset? Or are you trying to make the background color extend a few pixels outside the span text?

Comment: If you look at the picture I included each word in centered within an area that matches the others. Mine takes up only enough space for the actual word, which means that visually they aren't symmetrical.

Comment: @Kim Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. Please check the updated demo. The main ideas are that we set some of the elements to `display: inline-block` so that we can add padding to them, change their height and width, etc.

Comment: this part of the code gives me the affect I want and works with the rest of my codebase...thanks .leftlabel, .rightlabel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make the left and right labels a class which can be referenced from the style block: 
Now the style statements are

```
.left{
  text-align: center;
  width:40px;
  color:white;
  background: darkred;
  padding:3px;
}
.right{
  text-align: center;
  width:40px;
  color:white;
  background: purple;
    padding:3px;
}


     -------------HTML-------------------
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend>
    <label>Height:</label>
        <label for="height" class="left">Short</label>
  <input type="range" id="height" name="height" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="81">
  <label for="height" class="right">Tall</label><br>
    <label for="salary">Salary:</label>
        <label for="salary" class="left">Low</label>
         <input type="range" id="salary" name="salary" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="18">
        <label for="salary" class="right">High</label> <br>
</fieldset> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using input instead of label? :) you can easily style input, and yes, it can be textarea

Comment: @petr...If I weren't following specific instructions I would...thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your css, sorry I'm on a phone so can't test first.

```
label {

text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Can't you test and post answers once your off the phone?